# Batch convert Malformed PDFs to TIF on Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I need to convert a multipage PDF to TIF, but it appears to be a malformed PDF provided by our client. I tried using ImageMagick and GhostScript, but they do not convert the file correctly. The result is only about 85-90% correct. The only thing I've found that appears to do the job is GIMP, but I can't find an example to use it via its Batch Processing methods for PDFs.

Here are the warnings I get from ImageMagick and GhostScript:

```
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: FORMS$.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: P06BOB.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN308E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: P06BOB.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN308E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: P06BOB.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN308E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN307A.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN104A.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN308E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN208E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN308E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN208E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: HE14BP.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN208E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN106E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN208E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN106E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN208E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: HE08BP.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: HE11BP.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: AR10NP.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN308E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: JIMP2.l Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: HS11C.l Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: FORMS$.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN104A.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN208E.f Assuming it's a font name.
 **** Warning: Tf refers to an unknown resource name: UN307E.f Assuming it's a font name.

 **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
 **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
 **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
 **** specification.
```

I'm open to other suggestions too. Thanks!

EDIT: I am testing with GhostScript 8.7 and ImageMagick 6.5.4.7-6

Comment: An example file would be very helpful :)

Comment: I'd love to provide one, but since it's a client file, I cannot

Comment: Have you tried opening it in Adobe Acrobat (or even Reader)? Those are perhaps the most forgiving PDF readers on the market. If that would work there are implementation of technology out there that can be batched. Acrobat itself can be scripted and automated and the underlying technologies are used to create other command-line and hot folder automated tools.

Comment: Yes, Adobe opens the file just fine, however when we try to convert the file to TIFF to fax it, the conversion fails due to the malformed nature of the file. I haven't found a way to do this with Adobe and since we have 300+ in a batch, I certainly cannot do it by hand.

Comment: Have you tried opening it in Adobe Acrobat and choosing "Save as image > TIFF"? If it opens correctly I would expect the save as image to work as well... Alternatively (watch out, I'm affiliated with this company), download callas pdfToolbox Desktop - it can open, save as TIFF and can batch a whole folder of files if you find one file works correctly.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: Use Adobe Reader to convert the file to PostScript (there's a command line option for it) and convert the PostScript to TIFF with ImageMagick.

Comment: GS 8.7 is old; try the latest (9.06 or so).

Comment: If you cannot provide a sample pdf, you had better analyze the nature of the defect in the PDF. The output looks like some font resource is missing or referenced in a wrong way. *Tf* is the font setting operator, and it expects the **name** of a font **resource** as parameter. Quite often you see people instead supplying the **font name** itself. Maybe that is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

can't make any substantial comments without seeing the file. Have you considered simply sending the file back and telling them to make a proper one ?

Also you don't say what versions of GS and ImadeMagick you are using.

Comment: I can't provide one. We're not allowed to post client data in public forums. I am using GhostScript 8.7 and ImageMagick 6.5.4.7-6

Comment: Well I'd suggest upgrading your Ghostscript. Assuming you mean 8.70 then that is (I think) 3 and a half years old, the current version is 9.06. Can your client not create a PDF file of this type for you  without exposing confidential information ? I can't say if the file is valid, or work on a fix, without seeing an example of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Broken PDFs ... I "love" them. Actually, a strange but good idea is, to "print" the pdf - into another pdf- or ps-file. This can help a lot.

Comment: We tried to do something like that, but it didn't work. We have a crappy solution which uses GIMP + 2 other utilities that works, but the output is much lower res.

Comment: That's odd. Have you looked into "alternative" pdf printers like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFCreator ? (Well, you're asking for Linux, I guess - this would be a Windows thing ...)